# InterpolatingFunction in NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

I'm trying to get NSolve to solve a simple system of equations. It makes use of various interpolating functions (for thermodynamic properties). I can solve the system outside of NSolve by ordering the equations, but since more complex equations will be added later, I'd prefer to have Mathematica solve it.

My main issue is that I can't get Mathematica to give me values for the interpolating functions used. The equation system is much larger than this, but I get the error even on a single point in the process:

```
deltaTsub = -2;
Tc = 310;(*in K*)
NSolve[{
      T[4] == Tc + deltaTsub,
      p[4] == Evaluate[PTL[Tc, 0.5] ] ,
      h[4] == Evaluate[HTP[T[4], p[4]]],
      s[4] == Evaluate[STP[T[4], p[4]]]}]
```

with `HTP` (Enthalpy as a f(Temperature, Pressure)), `PTL` and `STP` being interpolating functions, defined like this:

```
HTP = Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{{T, p}, Enthalpy1[T, p]}, {T, 200., 330.,1.}, {p, 0.01, 0.65, 0.005}], 1]];
```

The solution I currently get looks like this:

```
NSolve[{T[4] == 308, p[4] == 0.488584, 
  h[4] == InterpolatingFunction[{{200., 330.}, {0.01, 0.65}}, <>][
    T[4], p[4]], 
  s[4] == InterpolatingFunction[{{200., 330.}, {0.01, 0.65}}, <>][
    T[4], p[4]]}]
```

It works just fine evaluating the function on pre-defined values like `Tc` but doesn't work once variables are introduced.

Comment: 1: I don't think `NSolve` is the right function for this problem. `FindRoot` is probably the one you want. 2: No solution variables are defined in your code; only the equations. 3: It's not possible for readers of SE to reproduce your problem because we have no definition of `Enthalpy1`. Finally, your use of `Evaluate` does nothing here since there are no functions with a hold attribute involved.

Comment: The expression you show as "the solution I currently get ..." is actually Mathematica's way of saying your `NDSolve` input expression is invalid and can't be evaluated, so I am puzzled by your further remark that "It works just fine". So I fine the question unclear.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: Thanks for your answer. 1. I tried `FindRoot[
 {t == Tc + deltaTsub,
  p == PTL[Tc, 0.5]  ,
  h == HTP[t, p],
  s == STP[t, p]}, 
 {{t, 300}, {p, 0.5}, {h, 270}, {s, 1.2}}]` (also tried it using two additional Arguments for boundaries), but I get a "FindRoot::nlnum" error message. 2. It doesn't matter now, but as I understood it (and tested with basic examples), if you don't specify any variables, it'll try and solve for all of them, which is what I want. 3. I'm not sure I can provide a fully reproducible example, since Enthalpy1 is from a connection to a substance database.

Comment: @m_goldberg Well, I only meant that Mathematica was able to use my function to determine `p[4]` but then did not manage to evaluate it for h[4]. Further: I didn't think there was anything invalid about it since I got no error message. In hindsight, that may have been naive. I do wonder exactly how it is invalid though. It just uses a user defined function in it.

Comment: @5plusspieldauer That's strange. Since I don't have a definition for `Enthalpy1`, I tried `HTP=STP= PTL= Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{{T,p},T p},{T,200.,330.,1.},{p,0.01,0.65,0.005}],1]];`.  With that, your `FindRoot` code works fine for me. Are you sure the interpolation functions return numeric values over the whole domain?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Apparently the issue was that the Interpolation had another function nested inside of it. I replaced it with the output of Enthalpy1 in the range as a table:
`Enthalpy1[T_, p_] := Enthalpy[refrigerant, "Tp", "SI", T, p];
htptable = 
  Flatten[Table[{{T, p}, Enthalpy1[T, p]}, {T, 200., 350., 1.}, {p, 
     0.01, 1.51, 0.01}], 1];
HTP = Interpolation[htptable];`
With that, FindRoot gets me results! Thanks for your help!